# Arrival times of taxis is poisson process

Tags: probability, poisson-process

You are waiting in line for a taxi. There are two people ahead of you. Taxis arrive in a
Poisson process, at average rate of one every two minutes

Let T$_2$=time until 2nd taxi arrives

I'm trying to find the CDF for T$_2$, The answer I'm given is F$_T$$_2$(t)=1-(1+λt)e$^($$^-$$^λ$$^t$$^)$

Can anyone explain or give me a hint on how to do this?

Comment: Sum of two i.i.d. exponential random variables has a Gamma or Erlang distribution.  Try a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$ and the probability that at least two events occur, i.e. $1 - $ the probability zero or one occur

Answer (score 0):

Let $\tau_n$ be the interarrival times of the taxis, i.e. $\tau_n\stackrel{i.i.d.}\sim\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda)$, where we may interpret $\lambda$ as $\frac12\mathrm{min}^{-1}$ or $30\mathrm{h}^{-1}$. Then $T_2=\tau_1+\tau_2$, so the density of $T_2$ is (for $t>0$)
\begin{align}
f_{T_2}(t) &=f_{\tau_1}\star f_{\tau_2}(t)\\ &= \int_0^t f_{\tau_1}(s)f_{\tau_2}(t-s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda s}\lambda e^{-\lambda(t-s)}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \int_0^t \lambda\ \mathsf ds\\
&= (\lambda t)\lambda e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align}
Integrating yields
\begin{align}
F_{T_2}(t) &= \int_0^t f_{T_2}(s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_0^t(\lambda s)\lambda e^{-\lambda s}\ \mathsf ds\\
&=\lambda s e^{-\lambda s}|_t^0 + \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda s}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= -\lambda te^{-\lambda t} + 1 -e^{-\lambda t}\\
&= 1 - (1+\lambda t)e^{-\lambda t},\ t>0.
\end{align}